# ClickListener current target

Tags: android, event-handling, listener

```
EditText etHomePhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pi_home_phone);
EditText etMobilePhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pi_home_phone);

etHomePhone.setOnClickListener(showPopUpClickListener);
etMobilePhone.setOnClickListener(showPopUpClickListener);


    private View.OnClickListener showPopUpClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

              /* I like to get both EditText.getText().toString() value in this one ClickListener 
 is it Possible, there is something in ActionScript call event.currentTarget...
*/  

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your etHomePhone and etMobilePhone variables as final and define your OnClickListener inline in the same method, then you can refer to those variables directly. Like so:

```
final EditText etHomePhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pi_home_phone);
final EditText etMobilePhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pi_home_phone);

View.OnClickListener showPopUpClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String home = etHomePhone.getText().toString();
        String mobile = etMobilePhone.getText().toString();
        // Do something with home and mobile
    }
};

etHomePhone.setOnClickListener(showPopUpClickListener);
etMobilePhone.setOnClickListener(showPopUpClickListener);
```

EDIT:

If you only want to get the text for the EditText that was clicked instead of both of them, then you can just cast the View that it delivered via onClick(View v):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText editText = (EditText)v;
    String phoneNumber = editText.getText().toString();
    // Do something with phoneNumber
}
```

Comment: Sorry i think i didn't make you understand what i want, I want something like....   String home or mobile = value of EditText which is calling this listener right now.

Comment: Just to clarify, I thought you wanted to get both of them within the method at the same time. Do you want to get the text for only the one that was clicked? If so, I've edited my post above with a solution.

Comment: thats what i wanted, Thanks :)

Comment: i have another problem if you have time can you check, Thanks   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904551/how-to-disable-background-screen

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet, so I can't see the context but you can structure a single OnClickListener to catch all events in your activity. First, your activity will need to implement the OnClickListener interface:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {...
```

In the OnCreate() method, register each UI element which should respond to clicks like this:

```
yourObject.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Next, for the activity's onClick() method, create a switch structure using R.id like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   switch(view.getId()){
   case R.id.A_UI_Element:
      //do what you need for this element
      break:
   case R.id.A_Different_UI_Element:
      //do what you need for this element
      break;
   //continue with cases for each element you want to be clickable
   }
}
```

Don't forget the break at the end of each case.

One thing I noticed in your code: both editText declarations refer to the same resource. This gives you two handles to the same UI element, not 2 different elements.

Comment: Thanks for you reply too, yes my editText refer too same resources that was mis type, actually its not.